# Is it valid to add `null` to a SynchronizedCollection - documentation error and/or removed restriction?

Tags: c#, collections, synchronizedcollection

Per [`SynchronizedCollection.Add`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms619841(v=vs.110).aspx), an ArgumentException is thrown when "The value set is null or is not of the correct generic type T for the collection". ReSharper 8 also considers this a [NotNull] parameter.

However, there is no exception when running the following code in LINQPad:

```
new SynchronizedCollection<string>().Add((string)null);
```

Furthermore, inspection of SynchronizedCollection.Add reveals it delegates down to [`List.Insert`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sey5k5z4(v=vs.110).aspx) which does not have this limitation. ("The object to insert. The value can be null for reference types."

Given this conflicting information and behavior, is it valid to add `null` to a SynchronizedCollection?

Did it used to be the case that adding a `null` value would have raised an exception?

Comment: Looks like a documentation bug to me.  Not the only one: "Adds an item to the thread-safe, read-only collection.".  Read-only?  Use connect.microsoft.com to report it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a documentation error. The exception only happens on `IList.Add(object)` (or any other `IList` method) not the normal `Add(T)`.

Also the error only happens if `T` is a value type and you pass in null, it does not happen for non value types.

From [the Reference Source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.ServiceModel/System/ServiceModel/SynchronizedCollection.cs,266)

```
public class SynchronizedCollection<T> : IList<T>, IList
{
    //...

    int IList.Add(object value)
    {
        VerifyValueType(value);

        lock (this.sync)
        {
            this.Add((T)value);
            return this.Count - 1;
        }
    }

    //...

    static void VerifyValueType(object value)
    {
        if (value == null)
        {
            if (typeof(T).IsValueType)
            {
                throw DiagnosticUtility.ExceptionUtility.ThrowHelperError(new ArgumentException(SR.GetString(SR.SynchronizedCollectionWrongTypeNull)));
            }
        }
        else if (!(value is T))
        {
            throw DiagnosticUtility.ExceptionUtility.ThrowHelperError(new ArgumentException(SR.GetString(SR.SynchronizedCollectionWrongType1, value.GetType().FullName)));
        }
    }
}
```

If you look at the error info

> The value set is null or **is not of the correct generic type T for the collection**

That situation is not possible with `Add(T)` you will get a compiler error instead of a runtime error. You could only pass in a non correct generic type if the parameter was of type `object` to get the run-time exception of `ArgumentException`.

Comment: Ahh, that makes a bit more sense as to how the documentation may have become the state it is, thanks!